# how to add done button in keypad

Tags: iphone

i need to add button done on keypad.

Apple does n't provide such felicity but some of application i found that done ,next,previous buttons.

[like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/864d6148cd.png).

how can i add these and how can i give click event to them.

can any one please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Define the done button (= return key):

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

2.Add the action-listener:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDoneEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

3.Define the action-event:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Have fun!

**EDIT:**

Here you can find detailed instructions how to add a Toolbar with Next & Previous above UITextField Keyboard:
http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/

**EDIT2:**

Now, I have a really great example for you: "This view extends UITextView adding on top of the keyboard associated with this UITextView a toolbar with a « Done » Button"

I check the code and it is a lot of easier than the first example:

http://blog.demay-fr.net/2009/07/cocoa-how-to-add-a-toolbar-with-button-on-top-of-a-uitextview-in-order-to-add-a-dismiss-button/

**EDIT3:**

Hmmm, no, I doesn't test to code. But I will test it now!

1.Problem: the right initialization. If I add the UITextView in IB, initWithCoder gets called:

```
- (id)init {

    NSLog(@"init");

    if (self = [super init]) {
        //register a specific method on keyboard appearence
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    NSLog(@"initWithCoder");

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
        //register a specific method on keyboard appearence
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    NSLog(@"initWithFrame");

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        //register a specific method on keyboard appearence
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

2.Problem: There's no view with the the Prefix "UIKeyboard":

```
for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    NSLog(@"keyboardWindow = %@", keyboardWindow);
    for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"keyboard = %@", keyboard);

            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"&lt;UIKeyboard"] == YES) {
                // THERE'S NO VIEW 'UIKeyboard'!!!
            }

    }
}
```

The code doesn't work, I'm sorry... I don't know why there's no view "UIKeyboard"... Maybe the first example will help you at this point and you can build your own solution.

Comment: Thank u Manni,But i need only done button,when i click it,i need to hide keyboard.I am getting confusion with this Tutorial.If u have any  sample please post it

Comment: I found a second example with a Done-Button on top of the keyboard. I hope that helps you :-) (look EDIT2)

Comment: I tried this(EDIT2),but does n't work,I did n't get any tool bar on the key board.Did u test this.

Comment: ya, Thank u for u r helping Manni,I use first link,That resolve my problem